# Requested unknown parameter 'ref' for row 0 in Datatables Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I spent more than an hour to fix it out, I am getting warning

> Requested unknown parameter 'ref' for row 0

Here is my code

```js
var oTable = $('#owned_properties').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bRegex": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ref" },
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "category_id" },
        { "data": "region_id" },
        { "data": "area_location_id" },
        { "data": "sub_area_location_id" },
        { "data": "beds" },
        { "data": "size" },
        { "data": "price" },
        { "data": "agent_id" },
        { "data": "dateadded" },
        { "data": "unit" }
    ],
    "sDom": '<>rt<ilp><"clear">',
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url();?>test/datatable",
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
    },
    'fnServerData': function (url, data, callback) {
        data.landlord_id = init_id;
        $.getJSON(url, data, function (json) {
            callback(json)
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="owned_properties">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Reference</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Region</th>
      <th>Main-Location</th>
      <th>Sub-Location</th>
      <th>Beds</th>
      <th>Sqt Ft</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Agent</th>
      <th>Listed</th>
      <th align="center"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead id="searchbox2" class="search_box">
    <tr>
      <form id="myForm3">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my Codeigniter code is

```
$this->datatables>select(ref,type,category_id,region_id,area_location_id,sub_area_location_id,beds,size,price,agent_id,dateadded,unit)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["GIS-R-0001","1","1","1","6032","0","1","3223","10000000.00","1","2016-01-10 09:45:36","1602"]
```

Comment: The markup of the table is invalid. `form` isn't a valid child element of `thead`

Comment: This is not the case,I tried with out form tag but still not working

Comment: Nonetheless the markup is invalid. Also the `thead#searchbox2` is missing a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're referring to the data by name, eg:

```
"data": "ref"
```

But your json doesn't use this naming.  If you remove all the `"columns"` from the initialisation code, you'll find it works:

```
var oTable = $('#owned_properties').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bRegex": true,
    //"columns": [
    //    { "data": "ref" },
    //    { "data": "type" },
    //    { "data": "category_id" },
    //    { "data": "region_id" },
    //    { "data": "area_location_id" },
    //    { "data": "sub_area_location_id" },
    //    { "data": "beds" },
    //    { "data": "size" },
    //    { "data": "price" },
    //    { "data": "agent_id" },
    //    { "data": "dateadded" },
    //    { "data": "unit" }
    //],
    "sDom": '<>rt<ilp><"clear">',
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/yhs9k2x1/1/)